# Is it wrong to call MPI_Bcast several times?

Tags: c++, mpi

I'm trying to implement Matrix-Vector multiplication using MPI (i.e. `nxn` matrix multiplied by `nx1` vector).

Originally, I decided to use multiple `MPI_Bcast` calls (before I noticed `MPI_AllGather`...) and I stumbled upon some strange behaviour. Apparently, data can be received no matter what rank is passed to `MPI_Bcast` call.

Part of the code used (the functions are called right after each other, so sending broadcast is before receiving broadcasts). Prints are just for debugging purposes, where I know testing data is of length 2:

```
class Processor
{
public:
    Processor(int rank, int communicatorSize);

private:
    void broadcastOwnVectorToOtherRanks();
    void receiveBroadcastsFromOtherRanks();
    //...

    int ownRank;
    int communicatorSize;
    std::vector<int> ownVectorPart;
    std::vector<int> totalVector;
    //...
};

void Processor::broadcastOwnVectorToOtherRanks()
{
    //ownVectorPart is correctly filled before this function call
    std::printf("Own data in vector %d %d\n", ownVectorPart[0], ownVectorPart[1]);
    MPI_Bcast(ownVectorPart.data(), ownVectorPart.size(), MPI_INT, ownRank, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}

void Processor::receiveBroadcastsFromOtherCommunicators()
{
    for (int rank = 0; rank < communicatorSize; ++rank)
    {
        if (rank == ownRank)
        {
            totalVector.insert(totalVector.end(), ownVectorPart.begin(), ownVectorPart.end());
        }
        else
        {
            std::vector<int> buffer(ownVectorPart.size());
            MPI_Bcast(buffer.data(), ownVectorPart.size(), MPI_INT, rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            std::printf("Received from process with rank %d: %d %d\n", rank, buffer[0], buffer[1]);
            totalVector.insert(totalVector.end(), buffer.begin(), buffer.end());
        }
    }
}
```

Outcome (sorted by rank):

```
[0] Own data in vector 0 1
[0] Received from communicator 1: 6 7
[0] Received from communicator 2: 4 5
[0] Received from communicator 3: 2 3
[1] Own data in vector 2 3
[1] Received from communicator 0: 0 1
[1] Received from communicator 2: 4 5
[1] Received from communicator 3: 6 7
[2] Own data in vector 4 5
[2] Received from communicator 0: 0 1
[2] Received from communicator 1: 2 3
[2] Received from communicator 3: 6 7
[3] Own data in vector 6 7
[3] Received from communicator 0: 4 5
[3] Received from communicator 1: 2 3
[3] Received from communicator 2: 0 1
```

---

As you can see, in process with rank 0 and 3 data received is different than data sent. For example, process with rank `0` received data from rank `3`, even though it is expecting data from process `1`.

It seems to me that rank is disregarded when receiving broadcast data, and MPI assigns data as it comes, whether it was from expected rank or not.

Why does `MPI_Bcast` receive data from process with rank `3`, when rank passed as argument is `1`? Is calling `MPI_Bcast` multiple times at the same time an undefined behaviour? Or is there a bug in my code?

Comment: You are mixing communicators with root rank. In your snippet, there is only one communicator and it is `MPI_COMM_WORLD`. All the ranks of the communicator must invoke `MPI_Bcast()` with the **same** root rank, and I suspect that is not the case in your program, and hence the undefined behavior. Please upload a [MCVE] if you need more help.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Yes, sorry for the confusion about communicators and ranks. My problem is, all ranks are trying to broadcast data. Firstly, each one sends single broadcast (in `broadcastOwnVectorToOtherCommunicators()`), secondly every rank tries to receive broadcasts from all other ranks (`receiveBroadcastsFromOtherCommunicators()`). Multiple brodcasts are being exchanged at the same time. I'll edit the question to try and clear it up.

Comment: And yes, all broadcasts are received. e.g. process with rank `3` will send one broadcast and receive total of 3 broadcasts from `0`, `1` and `2`. But the received data is mixed up, as if the `rank` argument in `MPI_Bcast` was ignored.

Comment: Once again, you are likely misusing `MPI_Bcast()`. All the ranks of the communicator must invoke the collective subroutine with the same `root` argument. I can only confirm it if you edit your question with a [MCVE]

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet What is missing from Complete example? `main()`? PBS file for `qsub`? I could refactor it to avoid classes to try to simplify it? I'm trying to explain that all processes will call `MPI_Bcast` with the given `root` *eventually*. All processes will **at some point** call it with `root == 0`, with `root == 1`, etc. If this is not allowed, that's all I'm asking about.

Comment: [MCVE] can at the very least be compiled and ran.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the MPI 3.1 standard (section 5.12):

> All processes must call collective operations (blocking and nonblocking)
>   in the same order per communicator. In particular, once a process calls
>   a collective operation, all other processes in the communicator must
>   eventually call the same collective operation, and no
>   other collective operation with the same communicator in between.

Combine this with section 5.4:

> If comm is an intracommunicator, MPI_BCAST broadcasts a message from
>   the process with rank root to all processes of the group, itself
>   included. It is called by all members of the group using the same
>   arguments for comm and root.

I interpret these two sections to mean that you must call `MPI_Bcast` and similar collective communication functions in the same order with the same arguments on all processes. Calling with different root values is invalid.

I believe `MPI_Allgather` is more suited to the communication you seem to want. It gathers equal amounts of data from all processes and copies it to each process.